# Risk of Using 0.0.0.0/0 for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, heroku, quotaguard

I am wondering what is the security risk associated with having 0.0.0.0/0 for MongoDB databases on Atlas? I am hosting a Discord Bot on Heroku and I have been banging my head trying to figure out how to set up the static IPs with QuotaGuard. At this point, I want to know the risk and the potential problems (realistically) with allowing access from anywhere.

Comment: don't know anything about heroku/quotaguard, but in general if you're exposing mongo server to the world, you should definitely have authentication enabled and SSL/TLS encryption setup so that nobody can snoop on the mongo traffic. also might wanna setup some kind of brute-force prevention. but ideally you should not expose mongodb to the world and have a rest api service which is exposed to the world and only that service talks to mongodb directly which can be located in the same machine/network.

Comment: When you mention authentication @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ , is that the default stuff that I set up as the database URI with the username and password in it? Also, I did not even know brute-force prevention is a possibility with MongoDB! Mind explaining all that in an answer to this question by chance?

Comment: I have an application and was wondering this exact same thing. Were you able to find an answer? I can't get QuotaGuard to work either for my backend on Heroku so... A little annoying.

Comment: @Donnygroezinger, unfortunately, I was not able to find it properly. QuotaGuard has some links that I found on the matter but I was not able to parse it effectively. Eventually, I just purchased a virtual private server through Vultr and just host everything through there. It comes out to 72$/year but I have the ability to host literally whatever I want on that server.

Comment: Nice, I just have a front-end mobile application that sends some GET requests and so I was just wondering if keeping the mongoDB open to all IPs is really that bad... Hasn't been an easy few days with support that's for sure. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is one of the trickier setups out there, but we've gotten pretty good at getting this running for a lot of customers. Since the admin's won't let us paste links of our documentation of how to do it yourself, and it's a long set of steps, I'd encourage you just to reach out to us at Support so we can help you get the connection set up and running quickly.